# URLFetch does not support granular timeout settings, reverting to total or default URLFetch timeout

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, urllib3, urlfetch

We have an application (app-a) that is on python2.7 standard google app engine. We are attempting to do programmatic authentication to access another application (app-b) using service account based on the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto). App-b is on python3.7 standard google app engine.

When we do the iap authenticated call we get the following error in the logs of App-A.

```
resp = requests.request(
    method, url,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
        google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)

AppEnginePlatformWarning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App Engine sandbox instead of sockets. To use sockets directly instead of URLFetch see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html.

AppEnginePlatformWarning: URLFetch does not support granular timeout settings, reverting to total or default URLFetch timeout.
```

The requests.request errors with

```
 Exception("Bad response from application: 500 / {'content-type': 'text/html', 'x-cloud-trace-context':
```

In App-B we are trying to receive the data sent from app-a.

```
json.loads(request.data)
```

We get the following error in the logs of app-b.

```
in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This leads me to believe that app-a is able to call app-b successfully. But for some reason it is not able to pass the data. Please help.

UPDATE - 
Per suggestion to use HTTPlib we tried this.

```
payload = {
    'test_data' : "data_test"
}

payload_json_dumps = json.dumps(payload)


conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
conn.request("POST", path, payload_json_dumps, request_headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
```

Added the following to app.yaml.

```
env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'true'
```

In App-B we changed to

```
from flask import request

@app.route('url', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def content_from_client(): 
    if (request.data):
        data_received = request.get_json()
```

We are still not able to get the data on App-B. We get

```
AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'")
```

UPDATE -

Changed the header formation and got it working.

```
   request_headers = {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json', 
        "follow_redirects": False,
        "X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid": "app-A.appspot.com",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(google_open_id_connect_token)
    }
```

Comment: What is the data you are sending? Do you call `json.dumps(data)` before sending it?

Comment: We do a json.dumps(payload) before sending the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppEnginePlatformWarning` is raised by urllib3 which is used by the [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/).

[Urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html#module-urllib3.contrib.appengine) provides a pool manager that uses [URL Fetch API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests) by default. Sometimes though may not be the best option for your use case. A solution is to use sockets instead. In order to do that you have to configure your `app.yaml`and include the following field:

```
env_variables:
    GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'true'
```

You may also find this documented in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#making_httplib_use_sockets).

As of the error on your app-B I would use [response.json()](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method, `requests` builtin method instead of `json.loads()` as it detects automatically which decoder to use.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain why the URLFetch doesn't work in this case? When you say "Urllib3 provides a pool manager... Sometimes that may not be the best option for your use case." Can you please explain what this means. Do we have to necessarily have to use Sockets? It is a low level implementation and we would like to avoid it. Is there any other parameter that we can set for URLFetch to make the POST call? This seems to be very foundational. It looks like app-A is calling app-B successfully - just not able to pass the data. Thanks for your suggestion response.json().

Comment: I am not familiar on how exactly URLFetch works but you may find more info in this  [Github issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/583) where it is stated that In order to make HTTPS connections you should use the sockets API instead of URLFetch.

Comment: I've enabled billing and added the GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB: 'true' I'm still receiving the AppEnginePlatformWarning

Answer (score 0):

Per suggestion above the following helped solve the issue. Changed to httplib instead of urlfetch.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
conn.request("POST", path, payload_json_dumps, request_headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
```

Added the following to app.yaml -

```
 env_variables:
    GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'true'
```

Changed header formation to -

```
  request_headers = {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json', 
        "follow_redirects": False,
        "X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid": "app-A.appspot.com",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(google_open_id_connect_token)
    }
```